# How to validate only after leaving focus of paper-input (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: validation, focus, polymer

I'm trying to get Polymer to only validate input for my paper-input once I leave the focus of the textbox. Here's a bit of code I have below:

```
<paper-input label="ZIP Code:" auto-validate pattern="\d{5}([-]\d{4})?" error-message="Invalid ZIP Code"></paper-input>
```

The above code works great at live validation and the regex allows the format 99999 and 99999-9999. However, as the user types, the error message will display until the regex pattern is met. What I want it to do is to not validate the input until the user leave the focus of the paper-input element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to only validate my input after leaving focus by using the onfocusout attribute

```
<paper-input id="zip" label="ZIP Code:" pattern="\d{5}([-]\d{4})?" error-message="This is not a valid ZIP Code" onfocusout="validate()"></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but answer is not completely right (and I can't just comment accepted answer cause I'm <50).

`onfocusout` sadly is not supported by firefox and can cause some issues with other browsers. Use `onblur` (or polymer's `on-blur`) instead.